# jQuery auto height adjust for tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am having a problem with the jQuery tabs. I am working on a website for a school and need some help with some javascript. You can see the page here:
[71.50.205.125/staugie.net/school/admin](http://goo.gl/WQsxM2), it is my working address. I added a user account for the username of "test" and password of "hi". Then once logged in, goto reports tab and see the right sidebar. See anything wrong? The jQuery background is not auto-extending. Feel free to use Google Chrome developer tools.

Comment: P.S. It is in an iFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see your reports folder properly... 
Your "tabs" content is not expanding because your folder's class `asside` has a fixed position.

What you can do is either put another div inside `tabs` for your tabs content and float that left and the `asside` right (with a relative positioning)

or

put a min width on your tabs.

```
min-height: 500px;
```

Comment: it is not working for some reason. I uncommented the background color property to see where the --minecraft term; 'hitbox' is. should I use the          aside tag for html5? or can you give a sample modified css for the ajax loaded content?